# Why did Larry Niven name his creature "Bandersnatch?"

Tags: animals, larry-niven, sentience, lewis-carroll

Why did Larry Niven call his immense armless, headless, sentient *Known Space* creatures *Bandersnatch?* How does the name relate to the Lewis Carroll beast mentioned in the "Jabberwocky"?

Comment: +1, often wondered this myself, but I believe the correct plural is "Bandersnatchi".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer? We don't really get an explanation. From *World of Ptavvs*:

> Winston Doheny, our biologist, took one look at these monsters and dubbed them *frumious bandersnatch*. This species name is now in the goddam log.

The biologist picked the name and it stuck. The implication to me was that the biologist picked the name simply as an example of a "strange beast". Could be worse... it could be a [*Boojum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(Lewis_Carroll))...

Comment: Funny you should mention "Boojum", 'cuz David Brin actually does mention it in the Uplift trilogy.

Comment: It's plausible that Carroll will remain well-known for centuries to come - the real tricky case is imagining that Cecil the Seasick Seaserpent will remain well-known enough to inspire the name for the Puppeteers

Comment: In Edward Bryant's contribution to *Berserker Base* (1985), the Berserker is nicknamed a "boojum" (although "gazebo" is also suggested).  Niven also contributed a Berserker story to the anthology honoring Saberhagen's creations.

Answer (score -4):

Niven read/liked Carroll's works. That's why a world is called Wunderland.
He also like Lord Lord Dunsany.

Comment: It would improve your answer to cite sources, and link your answer directly to Carroll's use of the word. (You also wrote one 'Lord' too many.)